# Member as chapter and company

Tags: contacts, organization

So I know that the Organization contact type is sort of used for two purposes. One it can be a chapter of the primary org that the CiviCRM is setup for and it can also be used for a company that a member is an employee for. What I don't know is how do you setup a contact to be part of your chapter and also set their employer? Do we need to add a custom field to the summary view so that we can create this extra relationship?

Our client, whom we are setting CiviCRM up for, has some chapters/sub-orgs under the main Non-profit org and a member could be part of that org. But when adding the member, if they want to provide the company they work for, we would need to allow for this as well.

The OTB setup only has the employer which is the org lookup field, so not really sure if the chapter use is intended to be an extra custom field or not.

Comment: is there a reason to not just use different types of relationships? org member; chapter member, etc.?

Comment: If you're setting up CiviCRM professionally, you'll find good help available for you at https://chat.civicrm.org!

Comment: Also, if you're implementing a chapter structure, there are many other considerations such as reporting, permissioning, etc. on a per-chapter basis.  Multisite CiviCRM is a common way to address this, but I wouldn't recommend that for your first CiviCRM project!

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally handle this with multiple relationships on the "Relationships" tab.

I suspect an unspoken requirement is that the Chapter relationship should be on the "Summary" tab.  You can do that with the [Relationship Block](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-block) extension, perhaps paired with [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) to position it where you want.

Comment: TY, the relationship is understandable, it was just that the only main field is for a company/employer and not for the org in which the member/contact could be tied to